# Bypass HTML entities

Tags: php, html, owasp, javascript-injection, websecurity

Is there anyway to bypass input sanitization and do HTML injection.

It is an exercise from bWAPP.When I am trying to do HTMLi , input validation is checked and special characters are sanitized.The code for sanitizing is attached , is there any other to bypass the code and do HTML injection?

```
function xss_check_3($data, $encoding="UTF-8")
{
    // htmlspecialchars - convert specialchars to HTML entities
    //  '&'(ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
    // '"'(double quotes) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set
    // "'"(Single quotes) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is 
      set
   // '<'(lessthan) becomes '&lt;'``
   // '>'(greterthan) becomes '&gt;'

  return htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, $encoding);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is the correct way to sanitize HTML input. That's basically what the function is designed for.

Note however that there might be issues if the input is not UTF-8 encoded

The PHP documentation on htmlspecialchars says (emphasis mine):

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with these conversions made. If you require all input substrings that have associated named entities to be translated, use htmlentities() instead.
>
> If the input string passed to this function and the final document share the same character set, this function is sufficient to prepare input for inclusion in most contexts of an HTML document. **If, however, the input can represent characters that are not coded in the final document character set and you wish to retain those characters (as numeric or named entities), both this function and htmlentities() (which only encodes substrings that have named entity equivalents) may be insufficient. You may have to use mb_encode_numericentity() instead.**

(*it is however not good enough to prevent SQL injection*)